# Sequelize JS: How to remove nested object in result set

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

When using sequelize.js how can I specify that the returned object does not contain included models as nested objects.

E.G.:

```
Model1.findAll({
  include: [{ model: Model2 }]
})
```

this will return:

```
{ id: X, ..., Model2: { ... } }
```

but I would like to get

```
{ id: X, ..., <model2 attributes> }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that without modifying the result object.

You have two options :

```
var _ = require("lodash");

Model1
    .findAll()
    .then( function( instance1 ) { 
        return instance1
            .getModel2()
            .then( function( instance2 ) {
                return _.extend(instance1.toJSON(), instance2.toJSON() );
            });
    }).then( function( instance1 ) { console.log(instance1) } );
```

This will create two database queries.

Your second option would be :

```
var _ = require("lodash");

Model1
    .findAll({
        include: [{ model: Model2 }]
    })
    .then( function( instance1 ) { return instance1.toJSON() } )
    .then( function( instance1 ) {
        var flatInstance = _.extend(instance1, instance1['Model2']);
        delete flatInstance['Model2'];
        return flatInstance;
    })
    .then( function( instance1 ) { console.log(instance1) } );
```

Which will use only one query.